# Customizing WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'd like to customize something in woocommerce.

Here is the example:

I've added some categories in woocommerce (Product Categories).
For example, there are two categories like "SALE" & "New Arrivals"
Now I want to put 2 drop downs in just one category for example I want all the products in "SALE" category to have 2 drop downs on each individual single product page.

There will be two drop downs like "Choose a color" & "Choose a fragrance".
This also needs to be integrated with the backend order dashboard so that each of that order shows the admin with the desired color and fragrance.

Please suggest since I'm not sure what to do.

Thank you!

Comment: Please add your code to the question, so we can see what you have tried already.

Comment: You can use WooCommerce Layered Nav widget https://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-widgets/ and place it wherever you want using some widget logic/conditional plugins like Dynamic Widgets, Conditional Widgets, Widget Logic or Jetpacks Widget Visibility Module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking is variable product. You can create variation  "Color" & "Fragrance". in variable products

When you are creating a product in backend you can select a product type as variable and add variations. You can see an example below

[image: example]